# iOS Share Extension issue when sharing images from Photo library

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, share, share-extension

Below is a code that I use to share images within my "ShareViewController.m".

```
NSExtensionItem *item = [self.extensionContext.inputItems objectAtIndex:i];
NSItemProvider *itemProvider = item.attachments.firstObject;

if ([itemProvider hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeURL]) {
     [itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeURL options:nil completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {

           NSLog(@"%@", data);

           // the rest of uploading script goes here

     }];
}
```

It all works fine if I share an image from WhatsApp. **But it doesn't work if I want to share an image from Photo Library or from Facebook Messenger**.

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I solved it. I got rid of `(NSString *)kUTTypeURL]` and added `itemProvider.registeredTypeIdentifiers` to get array with all the available type identifiers. Then I'm just using the first one available as `registeredTypeIdentifiers.firstObject`.

Also, **very important**, `NSData *data` got changed to `id<NSSecureCoding> item` which makes it a bit different to get the `NSData` from it. That's important especially when sharing images from Messenger - they have type identifier `"public.image"` rather than `"public.jpeg"` or `"public.url"` like in Photos library or WhatsApp.

```
NSExtensionItem *item = [self.extensionContext.inputItems objectAtIndex:i];
NSItemProvider *itemProvider = item.attachments.firstObject;

// get type of file extention (jpeg, file, url, png ...)
NSArray *registeredTypeIdentifiers = itemProvider.registeredTypeIdentifiers;

if ([itemProvider hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier:registeredTypeIdentifiers.firstObject) {
   [itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:registeredTypeIdentifiers.firstObject options:nil completionHandler:^(id<NSSecureCoding> item, NSError *error) {

           NSData *imgData;
           if([(NSObject*)item isKindOfClass:[NSURL class]]) {
                imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL*)item];
           }
           if([(NSObject*)item isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]]) {
                imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation((UIImage*)item);
           }



          // the rest of uploading script goes here

   }];
}
```

Comment: This answer is very useful. I was trying to share screenshot just after it is captured but when I was trying to access it by using kUTTypeImage it was returning data but damaged. Then this answer helped me to identify the problem area that instead of using NSURL or NSData, I should use id<NSSecureCoding> item. Added short description of my problem to help others. Thanks @ekashking