# iOS Share Extension issue with ItemProvider can't read from Photo library

Tags: ios, share-extension

I used the Solution form [iOS Share Extension issue when sharing images from Photo library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47385012/ios-share-extension-issue-when-sharing-images-from-photo-library) to get Images from the Photo App. This works great in the Simulator, but on the Device I get an error that I can't Access the NSURL provided by the itemProvider:

2018-02-18 12:54:09.448148+0100 MyApp[6281:1653186] [default] [ERROR] Failed to determine whether URL /var/mobile/Media/PhotoData/OutgoingTemp/554581B2-950C-4CFD-AE67-A2342EDEA04D/IMG_2784.JPG (s) is managed by a file provider

Caused by the Statment:

```
[itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:itemProvider.registeredTypeIdentifiers.firstObject options:nil completionHandler:^(id<NSSecureCoding> item, NSError *error) {
}
```

Searching PHAsset for the Item Name is not a good solution as the user have to grand access to the photo library again.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Do you find a solution for this?

Comment: Looks like there is no solution. Currently my code try to load the NSData from the URL and if it fails I load it from PHAsset (Building an Array of all PHAssets and searching for last path component as filename.) Realy bad code but in my tests it works for all Apps I have that allow image sharing.

Answer (score 2):

In didSelectPost you must not dismiss the ShareExtension ViewController until you have processed all the items in the inputItems array.  The ViewController is dismissed using [super didSelectPost] or by calling the completion method of the extension context.

Here is my solution in code:

```
- (void)didSelectPost {

__block NSInteger itemCount = ((NSExtensionItem*)self.extensionContext.inputItems[0]).attachments.count;
__block NSInteger processedCount = 0;
for (NSItemProvider* itemProvider in ((NSExtensionItem*)self.extensionContext.inputItems[0]).attachments ) {

    if([itemProvider hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier:@"public.jpeg"]) {
        NSLog(@"itemprovider = %@", itemProvider);

        [itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:@"public.jpeg" options:nil completionHandler: ^(id<NSSecureCoding> item, NSError *error) {

            NSData *imgData;
            if([(NSObject*)item isKindOfClass:[NSURL class]]) {
                imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL*)item];
            }
            if([(NSObject*)item isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]]) {
                imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation((UIImage*)item);
            }
            NSDictionary *dict = @{
                                   @"imgData" : imgData,
                                   @"name" : self.contentText
                                   };
            NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.share.extension1"];
            [defaults setObject:dict forKey:@"img"];
            [defaults synchronize];
            processedCount += 1;
            if (processedCount == itemCount)
                [super didSelectPost];
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: My solution looks similar, additionally I have a thired if: if( [(NSObject*)item isKindOfClass:[NSURL class]] ) and load the Image from PHPhotoLibrary.

Comment: I was struggling with this for hours... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `loadItemForTypeIdentifier` or in Swift `loadItem` method is **asynchronous** so dismissing the UI must be called as the last thing inside its `completionHandler`.

For example I have:

```swift
override func didSelectPost() {
    // This is called after the user selects Post. Do the upload of contentText and/or NSExtensionContext attachments.
    if let item = self.extensionContext?.inputItems[0] as? NSExtensionItem, let attachments = item.attachments {
        for provider in attachments {
            if provider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeImage as String) {
                provider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: kUTTypeImage as String, options: nil, completionHandler: {item, error in
                    // do all you need to do here, i.e.
                    if let tmpURL = item as? URL {
                        // etc. etc.
                    }
                    // and, at the end, inside the completionHandler, call
                    // Inform the host that we're done, so it un-blocks its UI. Note: Alternatively you could call super's -didSelectPost, which will similarly complete the extension context.
                    self.extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler: nil)
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I you dismiss the UI via:

```swift
self.extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler: nil)
```

or via:

```swift
super.didSelectPost()
```

outside of the `completionHandler` after the **async** method `loadItem` you will get all kind of permission errors, further more this errors could be random, sometimes happen and sometimes don't, this is because sometimes your **async** call to `loadItem` gets the chance to terminate before the UI is dismissed and sometimes it doesn't.

Just leaving this here, hoping it helps someone. This issue costed me few hours.